# Cumulative integration of elements of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I would like to to the following type of integration:

Say I have 2 arrays

```
a = np.array[1,2,3,4]
b = np.array[2,4,6,8]
```

I know how to integrate these using something like:

```
c = scipy.integrate.simps(b, a)
```

where `c = 15` for above data set.

What I would like to do is multiply the first elements of each array and add to new array called `d`, i.e. `a[0]*b[0]` then integrate the first 2 elements the arrays then the first 3 elements, etc. So eventually for this data set, I would get

```
d = [2 3 8 15]
```

I have tried a few things but no luck; I am pretty new to writing code.

Comment: It looks like you want something like `cumtrapz` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html), but using Simpson's rule instead of the trapezoidal rule.

Comment: So are you saying `d[i] = simps(b[:i+1], a[:i+1])`? edit: now I see @kikocorreoso has made that interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly what you need you could do the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

a = np.array([2,4,6,8])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
d = np.empty_like(b)
d[0] = a[0] * b[0]
for i in range(2, len(a) + 1):
    d[i-1] = integrate.simps(b[0:i], a[0:i])
print(d)
```

Comment: I think you want your range to go _through_ `len(a)`, so you want `range(2, len(a)+1)`, or better yet, `for i in range(1, len(a)): d[i] = ...[:i+1]`